# Project to learn JavaEE technologies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Attended a 2 week Java EE course and learnt the concepts. Want to try in a simple project and wanted ideas on what that could be? PetStore or Small Business App are so boring... Anything interesting that can be done to learn the breadth but at the same time it not being a full fledged project?

Comment: what in your mind is an interesting app?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763093/j2ee-fast-track-learning-enterprise-java-real-fast

Comment: J2EE? Really? It's upgraded to Java EE over 4 years ago. I'd question the value of the course as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider making

1. Test Case Tracker: Will allow folks to define a project. In each project, define modules. For each module define test cases. To each test case assign points. Each tester first creates test cases. Then later executes them (once approved). Track metrics against: Total points for components, Total points completed, Total points remaining, Total points blocked. Generate reports.
2. Personal Expense Tracker with monthly reports based on user-defined expense categories.
3. Team Activity Dashboard. Single dashboard page where people update their weekly planned activities.. and provide status/comments on work done. Will act like a weekly "status call"...except that you see it all the time active and available.

Answer (score 1):

You may find inspiration in the [seam examples](http://seamframework.org/Seam2/GettingStarted), and then try to build something similar.